# Unload js request on certain pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to unload a request that JqueryMobile is caching. On nearly all of my pages I use FastClick.js as it greatly decreases my click speed. This script is activated using onload="initFastButtons();" on the body tag. Is there a way that I can kill that request on certain pages? It is causing issues with some of my links on a particular page that I don't need fastclick. If I could just remove it, it would help with my issue. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do it with a data-xxx attribute on your body tag. Bind a jquery handler to only run initFastButtons when data-fastbuttons === "true".

Comment: Forgive me for being naive about this, but could you go into more detail. I'm more of a jquery novice. The other trouble that I would have is that I'm assuming that this would work on the index page and run the script and then cache for all the other pages with jquery mobile. Any help you can provide would be most appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 spec allows you to add data-xxx attributes on all elements to store metadata that you can use in your Javascript. This can be anything you like - with string data of course. So you can add an attribute to your body tag like so -

The next thing is to run your fastbutton code on a Jquery Mobile event rather than the body load. Have a look here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. You probably want to use the pageload or pagebeforeshow event.

When your event handler for the load event is called, you want to use the jqmData method (described here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html) to check whether the body tag has the fastbuttons attribute. If it does, run the code to initialise the fastbuttons.

I am not familiar with fastbuttons so don't know how it caches stuff.

Comment: Hey CodeMonkey, thanks so much for your help. I'm slowly still trying to figure this out. Can you let me know if I'm on the right path with the following...doesn't seem to work as is. Sorry if I'm completely off: git://gist.github.com/2783222.git

Comment: You're a rockstar. You've helped more than enough at this point, I feel bad for asking for more so this is your opportunity to check out. However I tried it and it didn't seem to work. I'm assuming that on the body tag I need to put something like this: "<body fastclick="page1">"?

Comment: No - the attribute has to be data-xxx so you want <body data-fastclick="page1">

Comment: Alrighty, still not working. I think I'm just gonna pull fastclick from the scripts to solve the issue. Really appreciate your help here though!